# Insert simplified Using Statement by Intellisense in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, intellisense, using

The AutoComplete Function in VS2017 suggests me fully qualified using statements.
I have two projects with following (simplified) structure:

```
Company.Contracts
  IMyExample.cs
Company.Core
  MyExample.cs
```

Now when I use `IMyExample` in Class `MyExample`, VS2017 suggests me a using statement like

```
using Company.Contracts
```

But I think that there was a time when VS2017 suggested me:

```
using Contracts
```

which is sufficient as the projects share the same main namespace.

How can I configure VS2017 so that it prefers simplified instead of fully qualified namespaces? In fact this is the opposite of [StyleCop Rule SA1135](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1135.md).

Hint: I was using VS2019 before but switchted back to VS2017 because the test licence ended and I'm pretty sure, that I didn't have to correct my using statements. Maybe in VS2019 this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe in VS2019 this is possible?

Sorry but the answer could be negative, I test it in VS2019 release 16.3.4 and confirm this behavior is not supported for now.

In your situation, instead of using [full qualified names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names), you can also use the format like `Contracts.ClassName`.

[image]

And for the reason why full qualified namespace is more preferred in this situation, assuming your current project `Company.Core` references one assembly whose root namespace is also named `Contracts`, now if VS do what you suggested, add the `using Contracts` when you use functions from `Company.Contracts` project, the intellisense would be confused about this. See:

[image]

In that situation you suggested, VS intellisense may get confused about what the `using Contracts` really mean, another assembly whose root namespace is `Contracts` or `Company.Contracts` project? So I think this could be one possible reason why it suggests full qualified namespace.

And if you do need one option which supports this behavior, I suggest you can send a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).The team would consider about it if this request gets enough votes.

Hope my answer makes some help:)